# A question about Copying SharePoint Lists

Tags: task-list

I want to make sure I have this correct. When I copy a SharePoint List, is it saved as a stp file to my local computer and I must have administrator rights in order to use that stp file as a template? If so, that's really not copying or duplicating a list, is it?  It's just creating a template of a list to use again later in SharePoint.

I want to make sure I have the process correct.

1. Select the List I want to duplicate.
2. Select List
3. Select List Settings
4. Select Save List Settings.

Another Question. Why the difference between File Name and Template name?

Answer (score 0):

When you copy a list, it saves as a list template in the site gallery. It is available for anyone who has the ability to create lists to create a new list based off of that template in that site collection (with content if saved with that option ticked). If it is to be used in a another site collection, it has to be downloaded locally and then uploaded to the desired site.

The template name is the descriptive name of the template, My custom Task List, and the file name is the filename, custom_list.